# Jquery Livevalidation email

Tags: jquery, livevalidation

Today, I faced a problem in live validation. When i enter in email in textbox as `xx@yy.com` ie . (space)xx@yy.com . It throws an error as 'Invalid email'. I want to trim the email and then validate in livevalidation

html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="255" class="element  text medium" name="email" id="email">
```

js

```
var f11 = new LiveValidation('email');
var f1 = f11.replace(/\s/g , '');// to remove space in email id
f1.add(Validate.Presence);
f1.add(Validate.Email);
```

I want to trim the email field then it can be validate by live validation. Any Ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you attach an "onChange" event to the input field using jQuery and have that clear any spaces in prefix/suffix; as user types?

html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="255" class="element  text medium" name="email" id="email">
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#email').change(function() { 
        $(this).val(
            $.trim(
                $(this).val()
            )
        );
    });
});
```